# How can I print out the content of a Dictionary<string, object>?

Tags: c#, dictionary, unity-game-engine, firebase-realtime-database

Firebase Databse Fails to download data when needed in between other similar operations in app.

> System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.Object]

Firebase Cannot take do new `GetValueASync` sometimes in middle of similar operations of app and returns `` System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.Object] `` as a snapshot value.

Steps to reproduce:

Setup any unity project with realtime databse perform non stop multiple times :
`.GetValueAsync().ContinueWithOnMainThread(task =>`
then you will get value as `` System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.Object] `` instead of any child/key/database value.

```
public void aaaa() {
    Reference.Child("Users").OrderByChild("About/XP").StartAt(1).LimitToFirst(12).GetValueAsync().ContinueWithOnMainThread(task => {
      if (task.IsFaulted) {

        return;
      } else if (task.IsCompleted) {
        DataSnapshot Snapshot = task.Result;
        if (Snapshot != null)
          Debug.Log(Snapshot.Value);
        return;
      }
      return;

    });
```

Answer (score 2):

#### The "issue"

Well this happens if you use [`ToString`](https://learn.microsoft.com//dotnet/api/system.object.tostring)  (which is what `Debug.Log` does internally) on a dictionary or in general any object of a type that doesn't implement it explicitly, it simply returns the same as `GetType().FullName`.

> Default implementations of the `Object.ToString` method return the **fully qualified name of the object's type**.

[`Firebase.Database.DataSnapshot.Value`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/unity/class/firebase/database/data-snapshot#value)

> returns the data contained in this snapshot as native types. The possible types returned are:
>
> - `bool`
> - `string`
> - `long`
> - `double`
> - **`IDictionary{string, object}`**
> - `List{object}`
>
> This list is recursive; the possible types for object in the above list is given by the same list.
>
> These types correspond to the types available in JSON.

So it looks like in your case the type is a `Dictionary<string, object>`.

You can easily confirm this

```
Debug.Log(new Dictionary<string, object>().ToString());
```

will print

```
System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.Object]
```

---

#### Solution 1a - Simple Loop

If you want to see all first level items you rather want to do e.g.

```
foreach(var kvp in Snapshot.Value)
{
    Debug.Log($"Key: {kvp.Key}, Value: {kvp.Value}");
}
```

Note though: while the key is a `string`, the value once again might be a type (afaik e.g. again a `Dictionary<string, object>`) not implementing `ToString` in which case again it will simply print out the type name.

#### Solution 1b - Recursive print

You could of course implement something covering this all recursive, somewhat like e.g. (untested)

```
public static class SnapthotExtensions
{
    public static string GetString(this DataSnapshot snapshot)
    {
        return GetString(snapshot.Value);
    }

    private static string GetString(this object obj)
    {
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        GetString(obj, sb);

        return sb.ToString();
    }

    public static void GetString(object obj, StringBuilder sb, int indent = 1)
    {
        switch (obj)
        {
            case bool b:
                sb.Append(b);
                break;

            case string s:
                sb.Append('"').Append(s).Append('"');
                break;

            case long l:
                sb.Append(l.ToString());
                break;

            case double d:
                sb.Append(d.ToString("G17"));
                break;

            case IDictionary<string, object> dict:
            {
                sb.Append("[\n");
                var i = 0;
                foreach (var kvp in dict)
                {
                    sb.Append(new string(Enumerable.Repeat(' ', indent * 2).ToArray()));
                    sb.Append('"');
                    sb.Append(kvp.Key);
                    sb.Append("\": ");
                    GetString(kvp.Value, sb, indent + 1);

                    if (i < dict.Count - 1) sb.Append(",\n");

                    i++;
                }

                sb.Append('\n');
                sb.Append(new string(Enumerable.Repeat(' ', indent * 2).ToArray()));
                sb.Append(']');
                break;
            }

            case IList iList:
                var list = iList.Cast<object>().ToList();

                sb.Append("[\n");
                for (var i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
                {
                    sb.Append(new string(Enumerable.Repeat(' ', indent * 2).ToArray()));
                    GetString(list[i], sb, indent + 1);
                    if (i < list.Count - 1) sb.Append(",\n");
                }

                sb.Append('\n');
                sb.Append(new string(Enumerable.Repeat(' ', indent * 2).ToArray()));
                sb.Append(']');
                break;

            default:
                throw new NotSupportedException($"Type {obj.GetType()} is not supported!");
        }
    }
}
```

and then use

```
Debug.Log(snapshot.GetString());
```

---

#### Solution 2 - Newtonsoft JSON

But if you really want to print out the entire structure (as far as the values are serializable) you could/should rather use [Newtonsoft JSON.Net](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/input-management/json-net-for-unity-11347) and convert the entire dictionary into a human readable JSON format. Then print out this JSON instead of implementing it yourself.

See [Serialize a Dictionary](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/serializedictionary.htm)

```
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Snapshot.Value, Formatting.Indented);
Debug.Log(json);
```

---

#### Solution 3 - Firebase specific

I found out that Newtonsoft isn't really needed in your specific case! (I'll leave it here as a general hack to print out dictionaries when not using Firebase)

Just use [`GetRawJsonValue`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/unity/class/firebase/database/data-snapshot#class_firebase_1_1_database_1_1_data_snapshot_1aeac5f8a0bcdf5bc3761a13f9f7081570)

> returns the data contained in this snapshot as a json serialized string.

so it is as simple as

```
Debug.Log(Snapshot.GetRawJsonValue());
```

Comment: the same code works fine and show me list of sorted users when not running any other getvalueasync beside.

Comment: @gputhread so? Apparently then it returns a type that does implement `ToString` in a meaningful way ...

Comment: it should return "firebase busy, try later" or "location/url not reached" bcoz it works fine while app is idle.

Comment: @gputhread again: What you get printed in the console **IS** the result. It is a `Dictionary<string, object>` which you can now use to further access the return values by the keys ... It prints `System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.Object]` because that is exactly what you get if you try to use `Debug.Log(new Dictionary<string, object>().ToString());` .. it just means there is no meaningful `ToString` implementation for this type but you got a valid result back

Comment: Solution 2 - Newtonsoft JSON : nice one, used this one & it was magical :)

Answer (score 0):

Please use loop

```
foreach( KeyValuePair<string, object> kvp in Snapshot.Value)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Key = {0}, Value = {1}",
        kvp.Key, kvp.Value);
}
```

Comment: What does this add that [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70423066/7111561) didn't cover? ;) Also Unity specific you do not want to use `Console.WriteLine`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).