# Retrieve data in nested for Firebase Realtime Database (Unity C#)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, firebase-realtime-database

I wanted to retrieve data and link that I put in a nested inside Firebase but I receive an error:

> System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.Object][]

I hope there's anyone who can help me solve this issue.

Here is the firebase nested looks like

[image: Image firebase databse]

Here is the code

```
private IEnumerator LoadCourse_1()
{
    //Get the currently logged in user data
    var DBTask = DBreference.Child("Course").Child("MDR3005").GetValueAsync();
   
    yield return new WaitUntil(predicate: () => DBTask.IsCompleted);

    if (DBTask.Exception != null)
    {
        Debug.LogWarning(message: $"Failed to register task with {DBTask.Exception}");
        
    }
    else if (DBTask.Result.Value == null)
    {
        //No data exists yet
        Course1.text = "-";
        Course1CodeName.text = "-";
    }
    else
    {
        //Data has been retrieved at dashboard
        DataSnapshot snapshot = DBTask.Result;
        Course1.text = snapshot.Child("CourseCode").Value.ToString() + ": " + snapshot.Child("CourseName").Value.ToString() ;
       
       
        //Data retrieve for course data
        Course1CodeName.text = snapshot.Child("CourseCode").Value.ToString() + "\n" + snapshot.Child("CourseName").Value.ToString();
        
        TM1.text = snapshot.Child("Notes").Value.ToString();
        
       

    }
}
```

Comment: Why is this se thing asked that often ...? o.O  .. see [How can I print out the content of a Dictionary<string, object>?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70423066/7111561) where I think I explained the "issue" and also a solution

Comment: I have tried the solution you shared in the link. But for foreach loop, the variable Snapshot got error even though I have matched it with the variable I used. I want to get the data value in list format. If you could help me, it will be much pleasure. @derHugo

Comment: Well as I see it your `snapshot.Child("Notes")` contains a dictionary and is further nested into `Chapter1` -> `Link` and `Name` .... so as I said in my linked answer ... this is no error at all but simply what you get when you try to use `ToString` on a dictionary ..

Comment: Sir, may I ask, I created a button with several texts in it to make it a prefab. Once I dragged the button to my assigned prefabs folder, the prefab doesn't have the arrow symbol that can expand the child at project column. Do yo know why? @derHugo

Comment: This was changed when Unity introduced the new nested prefabs and prefab editor (I think in 2018 if I remember correctly). Simply double click your prefab or in the hierarchy clock the little right arrow => this will open your prefab in the scene view and hierarchy => you are now in [prefab edit mode](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/EditingInPrefabMode.html) ;)

Comment: I see. because of unity version TT. I'm using 2020.3.13f1. course.transform.Find("?").GetComponent<Text>().text = xxx;.  When I filled in? with text name, I got the error Object reference not set to an instance of an object. so I think because the child prefab doesn't exist. @derHugo